# нужна помощь с выполнением задание

Tags: c++

Студент начал решать задачи данного урока программирования,
когда электронные часы показывали h1 часов и min1 минут, а закончил, когда
было h2 часов и min2 минут. Составьте программу, позволяющую определить,
сколько времени студент решал эти задачи. (Будем считать, что задачи
решались не дольше суток)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int h1, min1, h2, min2,h,min,m;
    cin >> h1 >> min1 >> h2 >> min2;
    m = (h2 * 60 + min2) - (h1 * 60 + min1);
    h = m / 60;
    min = m % 60;
    cout << h << ' ' << min;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Переход через полночь же не учитываете, когда время начала больше времени окончания. Что выведет ваша программа, если начал решать в 23:59, а закончил в 00:01?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = (h2 * 60 + min2) - (h1 * 60 + min1);
if (m < 0) m+= 60*24; // Переход через полночь
h = m / 60;
```