# Почему код не работает? не понимаю. Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int h1, min1, h2, min2, h, min;

    std::cout << "Введите кол-во часов: " << std::endl;
    std::cin  >> h1;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во минут: " << std::endl;
    std::cin  >> min1;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во часов: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> h2;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во минут: " << std::endl;
    std::cin  >> min2;
    if ((min2 - min1) >= 0) && ((h2 - h1) >= 0)
    {
        h = h2 - h1;
        min = min2 - min1;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных часов: " << h << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных минут: " << min << std::endl;
    }

    else if ((min2 - min1) < 0) && ((h2 - h1) >= 0)
    {
        h = h2 - h1 - 1;
        min = 60 + (min2 - min1);
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных часов: " << h << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных минут: " << min << std::endl;
    }
    
    else if ((min2 - min1) >= 0) && ((h2 - h1) < 0)
    {
        h = 24 - h1;
        min = min2 - min1;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных часов: " << h << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных минут: " << min << std::endl;
    }

    else if ((min2 - min1) < 0) && ((h2 - h1) < 0)
    {
        h = 24 - h1;
        min = 60 + (min2 - min1);
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных часов: " << h << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Кол-во затраченных минут: " << min << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Опишите хотя бы задачу, которую вы решали, ожидаемое поведение Вашей программы и фактическое поведение(возможно возникали какие-то ошибки?)

Comment: Если вместо `((min2 - min1) >= 0) && ((h2 - h1) >= 0)` записать `((min2 - min1 >= 0) && (h2 - h1 >= 0))`?

Comment: Хм... Дубликат: [нужна помощь с выполнением задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1325572)???

Comment: Я подправил условия (убрал лишние скобки внутри) и все нормально работает. Не считая кракозябр вместо русского текста.

Answer (score 1):

Как *правильно* выглядит оператор `if`?

```
if (условие) { ... }
```

А у вас?

```
if ((min2 - min1) >= 0) && ((h2 - h1) >= 0)
```

Т.е.

```
if (условие1) && (условие2) { ... }
```

Вы забыли скобки вокруг составного условия.

О русском языке см. [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342)